# Use child components as real components, not stateless child objects

Tags: reactjs

Some component contains a `Tabs` with `Tab`s:

```
class App {
  render() {
    <div>
      <p>Tabs here:</p>
      <Tabs>
        <Tab name="Page 1"> .. content here .. </Tab>
        <Tab name="Page 2"> .. content here .. </Tab>
        <Tab name="Page 3"> .. content here .. </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    </div>
  }
}
```

`Tabs` is responsible for most of the markup:

```
class Tabs {
  click() {
    // I want the Tab component, because I want to tab.setState()
    // `this` is not a `Tab` object
  }
  render() {
    return (
      ( print the tab labels: )
      <ul>
        { this.props.children.map(tab =>
          // >>> `tab` is not a `Tab` object <<<
          <li><a onClick={ this.click.bind(tab) } href="#">{ tab.props.name }</a></li>
        ) }
      </ul>

      ( print the tab content: )
      { this.props.children }
    );
  }
}
```

A `Tab` itself is very little, maybe nothing:

```
const Tab = ({children}) => <div>{ children }</div>;
```

How does `Tabs.click` know which `Tab` was clicked. If I `click.bind(tab)` it's the child object, not the Tab object. If I `click.bind(this)` it's the `Tabs` object.

This might be a very longwinded way of asking why `props.children` don't contain the Component objects, but a kind of proxy (?) child object. It does have the props, but not the methods, state etc.

**edit 1:**
In this example, I'd like to let `Tab` decide how to render itself: once as tab link and once as tab content. Tabs would be responsible for calling the render methods, but Tab would know how. As you can see in `Tabs.render()` there are 2 renders. It'd be nice if it could do this:

```
      <ul>
        { this.props.children.map(tab => tab.renderLink()) }
      </ul>

      { this.props.children.map(tab => tab.renderContent()) }
      or just
      { this.props.children }
      because content is the normal render
```

But `Tabs` can't do that, because it doesn't have `Tab` objects for `children`... Why?

Comment: Easiest way is to allow `<Tab />` to take an identifying value and pass it back up the chain when calling it's `onClick` function.  EG: You could pass `this.props.name` as 2nd argument on `onClick`.

Comment: @MikeDriver But I still won't have the `Tab` object then... Why doesn't props.children have the `Tab`objects? I want to `setState()` on a `Tab`, or read from its state, or do some `Tab` logic.

Comment: @MikeDriver I've added **edit 1** to the question with why I'd like real Tab objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few methods to achieve this. To start, you're right - since you're using ES6 arrow functions in the `map`, `this` isn't rebound - it's "inherited" from the enclosing scope (I think, technically, it's less inherited and more just left alone - unchanged).

First, instead of binding in the render method, bind `click` in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
}
```

or use ES6 Arrow Functions

```
click = (event) => {...}
```

Although this doesn't directly solve your issue, it cleans up the context mess that arises from using bound callbacks.

From there, you can get the clicked tab by using `event.target`.

You can also use partials - the `bind` method accepts additional parameters which are prepended to the parameters of the bound function. That would look something like this:

```
render (
    <div>
    { this.props.children.map((tab) => {
        <a <li><a onClick={ this.click.bind(null, tab) } href="#">{ tab.props.name }</a></li>
    }) }
);
```

you would have to adjust your `click` method to accept tab as well: `click(tab, event)`

I also don't think it's wise, or even recommended to mess with a component's state from another component. Why aren't you using the `Tab` component? Pass in `Tabs` `onClick` as a prop and handle click events like this...

```
class Tab extends React.Component {
    onClick = (event) => {
        this.setState({...}); // Tab onClick

        if (this.props.onClick) this.props.onClick(); // Tabs onClick
    }
}
```

edit: Working example

`Tabs` class

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
    onTabClick = (tab) => {
        tab.setState({ test: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.children.map((tab) => {
                    return React.cloneElement(tab, {
                        onClick: this.onTabClick
                    });
                }) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`Tab` class

```
class Tab extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
    }

    onClick = (event) => {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();

        if (this.props.onClick) {
            this.props.onClick(this);
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{ !this.state.test && <a href={ this.props.url } onClick={ this.onClick }>{ this.props.label }</a> }</div>;
    }
}
```

example tabs

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab url="http://www.google.com" label="Google" />
    <Tab url="http://www.google.com" label="Google" />
</Tabs>
```

although it begs the question again - why not just set the state inside of the `Tab` class? Why do you need to set the state of a child from within a parent? [Can that state not be maintained by the parent (using `this.setState(...)` and passed into the child as a prop?](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: `event.target` would be the DOM element. not the `Tab` object. The bindings aren't the problem. `props.children` doesn't even have the `Tab` object. If you do a `React.cloneElement`, will that reference the original `Tab` object?? Because the `tab` you clone isn't a `Tab` object, which is the problem.

Comment: Shared state in Tabs might be better, but I saw this in a Vue example and wanted to make it in React =) A `Tab` has dual display (the LIs and the content) so just rendering a `Tab` isn't enough. `Tabs` has to render every `Tab` twice. [This is what I came up with](https://github.com/rudiedirkx/react-test/blob/master/client/components/Tabs.react.jsx), but I'm not a big fan...

Comment: I've added **edit 1** to the question with why I'd like real Tab objects.